# binary to decimal number conversion

Tags: c, binary, numbers

I know how to find the decimal equivalent from the binary number. E.g. a general method of finding decimal equivalent of binary number (101.01) is (2^2)*1 + (2^1)*0 + (2^0)*1 + (2^-1)*0 + (2^-2)*1 .

My doubt is how can we find the decimal equivalent of lengthy binary numbers whose decimal equivalent range is from ±3.4×10^38. By lengthy I mean which contain large number of bits like 0.00000000000100100100010100010010101 etc.

I tried this with the general method given by me in starting, but using that method here leads to much time consumption and probability of getting wrong answers is also almost sure.

For the same I tried using calculator and online binary to decimal converter's, they are giving the approximate result but i need accurate result.

If using some software I can do that then please share that, my ultimate aim is to find the way to find the 100 % accurate decimal equivalent of range ±3.4×10^38 from lengthy binary numbers.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139541/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67275459/781723, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/425801/34181.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem originates from the computer not knowing how to handle very small (or large) numbers. Your CPU has a component called the ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit) which does the basic calculations on numbers with set number of bits in them. Since your numbers need more bits than an ordinary CPU can store, it causes rounding errors and miscalculations.

To solve this, you can use an Arbitrary-Precision Arithmetic software, which takes up more memory and simulates the computer's ALU for an infinite amount of bits (as many as your memory can handle) in exchange for memory and performance.

You can find such software [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software).